# I don't understand what shape the array in my functions argument is

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life, cellular-automata

I am trying to run conway's game of life using the function

```
animate_life(100, 'beacon',[0], 30, 300)
```

But it keeps popping up errors , in its current form it says :

```
x_start, y_start = seed_position[0], seed_position[1]
```

> IndexError: list index out of range.

Originally I had used an index that looked like `[0,1]` but this also reported an error, namely :

> IndexError: too many indices for array

I'm given to believe that giving it 2 values would report an issue because  you're expecting data to be a 2D array. Numpy is complaining because the data is not 2D (it's either 1D or None)?

My question is: what is the size of the data ?

I.e What size argument is expected in my `animate_life` function which is generally defined as:

```
animate_life(universe_size, seed, seed_position, n_generations=30, interval=300, save=False)
```

Edi: this is referring to the code found at https://github.com/robertmartin8/PyGameofLife/blob/master/game_of_life.py

Comment: How do you expect people to help you by mentioning a function without actually posting it? It's as if you've asked why `bob("abc")` raises a `ValueError`?

Comment: Where did you get `animate_life`? Is it from here: https://github.com/robertmartin8/PyGameofLife ?

Comment: You need to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Clarification: I am basing my answer on the code found here.
https://github.com/robertmartin8/PyGameofLife/blob/master/game_of_life.py

I am *completely and honestly sure* that the index should be a 2-tuple rather than a list, so you should try seed_position=(0,1).
Same for universe size; try (100,100).

Comment: with 50+ creds you are able to comment. use comments to get a clear question, **then** answer. believes do not belong into answers and the question is not clear _at all_

Comment: This was just a figure of speech. I was referring to this code, https://github.com/robertmartin8/PyGameofLife/blob/master/game_of_life.py, the only thing I am not sure of is whether the OP was also referring to the same code.

Comment: what hinders you to comment & ask if he really uses this?

Comment: That somebody already asked :) Sorry if I was too enthusiastic to answer that I did not wait for confirmation!

Comment: Seems you nailed it, +1 - lucky you.